# Generating isometric grid for tileset in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, grid, coronasdk, isometric, tiled

I imported an isometric map made in tiled to Corona SDK and am now trying to overlay a grid layer. I've done a lot of reading into isometric grids but it seems they all reference tilesets where the height is half the width. (ex. 128x64px ). I am using a tileset that requires the grid to be 256x149px and I think I have to edit the grid generation function to accommodate the change. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Screenshot of the issue (Using original Vectors):

[Original Vectors:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vUNB.png) https://image.ibb.co/emXpQR/Screen_Shot_2017_12_18_at_1_35_19_PM.png

[Edited Vectors (the ones commented out in code):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vUNB.png) https://image.ibb.co/ikxOkR/Screen_Shot_2017_12_18_at_1_35_54_PM.png

Grid Generation Code:

```
function drawGrid()
               for row = 0, 16  do
                  local gridRow = {}
                  for col = 0, 9 do

                    -- draw a diamond shaped tile
                    local vertices = { 0,-16, -64,16, 0,48, 64,16 }
                    -- MY EDITED VERTICES { 0,-37.25, -128,37.25, 0,111.75, 128,37.25 }
                    local tile = display.newPolygon(group, 0, 0, vertices )

                    -- outline the tile and make it transparent
                            tile.strokeWidth = 1
                            tile:setStrokeColor( 0, 1, 1 )
                            tile.alpha = .4

                            local tileWidth = 256
                            local tileHeight = 149

                    -- set the tile's x and y coordinates
                    local x = col * tileHeight
                    local y = row * tileHeight

                    tile.x = (x - y)
                    tile.y = ((tileHeight/2) + ((x + y)/2))

                    -- make a tile walkable
                    gridRow[col] = 0
                  end
                  -- add gridRow table to the map table
                  j_map[row] = gridRow
               end
            end
```

As you can see in the screenshots the tiles kind of veer off the side of the map. If anyone knows how to fix it or needs more info on the information let me know!

Comment: What do you use for rendering a isometric map in Corona SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code:

```
for row = 0, 16  do
      local gridRow = {}
      for col = 0, 9 do

        -- draw a diamond shaped tile
        --local vertices = { 0,-16, -64,16, 0,48, 64,16 }
        -- MY EDITED VERTICES 
        local vertices = { 0,-37.25, -128,37.25, 0,111.75, 128,37.25 }
        local tile = display.newPolygon( group, 0, 0, vertices )

        -- outline the tile and make it transparent
                tile.strokeWidth = 1
                tile:setStrokeColor( 0, 1, 1 )
                tile.alpha = .4

                local tileWidth = 256
                local tileHeight = 149

        tile.x = -(row - col) * tileWidth * 0.5 
        tile.y = (row + col) * tileHeight * 0.5 

        -- make a tile walkable
        gridRow[col] = 0
      end
      -- add gridRow table to the map table
      --j_map[row] = gridRow
   end
```

I get formula for `x`and `y` position of tile from [Isometric Tiles Math](http://clintbellanger.net/articles/isometric_math/). Good luck:)

Comment: Thank you very much! I also looked at the Isometric Tiles Math page bug could not figure out what i was doing wrong haha. Your solution worked though!